# Sharepoint list add icon to modified item

Tags: jquery, list, sharepoint, caml

I am using this caml query to select all items in a sharepoint list that were recently modified.
Now I want to add some kind of icon to the title as an identifier that the item was modified. Kind of like the new.png that sharepoint uses.

```
<Where>
      <Gt>
         <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
         <Value Type='DateTime'>
            <Today Offset='-7' />
         </Value>
      </Gt>
   </Where>
```

Update:
[image]
Does anyone have an example of this?

Marco

Comment: What is the version of your SharePoint?

Comment: sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show Modified in your list view,then select eligible items in csr and add icons.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
(function () {
    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = renderItem;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();


function renderItem() {
    
    
        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var Modified = rows[i]["Modified"];     
                console.log(Modified)
            var SevenDaysAgo=   new Date(new Date().getTime()-24*60*60*1000*7);
            if(SevenDaysAgo.getTime()<new Date(Modified).getTime()){
            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
            var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
            $(row).find("td>div[field='LinkTitle']").append("<img src='http://sp/Shared%20Documents/download.png'/>");
            }
            
            
        }

        ctx.skipNextAnimation = true;
    
   
}

</script>
```

Test Result:
[image]
Updated:

[image]

Comment: something goes wrong with the date comparison. For example my date modified is returned like Modified: 11-8-2020 08:30 and the var SevenDaysAgo like Wed Oct 7 11:14:43 UTC+0200 2020. Therefor the icon is displayed where it shouldn't

Comment: no both dates are correct. But when comparing he adds the icon to the wrong items.

Comment: You could debug the code and see the if the SevenDaysAgo.getTime()<new Date(Modified).getTime() is right.

Comment: I tried following but it only returns true console.log(new Date(Modified).getTime()<SevenDaysAgo.getTime())

Comment: so both dates are fine, it's just they have a different format. I am not sure it that is the issue. 11-8-2020 08:30 and Wed Oct 7 11:14:43 UTC+0200 2020

Comment: It should have nothing to do with the time format.Please check the update.

Comment: AMOS, I saw the update. I wouldn't know what else could cause it to go wrong in my system. What if I would leave out the time and just use the date? How to do that"?

Comment: Now it's October, and it is strange that your modofied time is in November.

Comment: no that date represents 11 august 2020. 11-8-2020. I like to add a screenshot but i dont think its possible in comments

Comment: You could share it in your question.

Comment: I tried but I dont have enough credits to upload pictures :(

Comment: I added a screenshot (thanks to Amos) which shows the strange date comparisons. I also tried to change one of the date formats `console.log("Modified: " + String.format("{0:i}",new Date(Modified)));`
However it doesn't do any good. I even get dates in the future now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The date in my list mixed up the month and the day, even though it displayed it correct. So I added some code to extract the day, month and year and put it back together as a correct date for the javascript. The only problem that remains is WHY does it not work like AMOS_MSFT suggested?

```
        var xDate = Modified.split(" ")[0];
        var xDateParts = xDate.split("-");
        var xYear = xDateParts[2];
        var xMonth = xDateParts[1]-1;
        var xDay = xDateParts[0];
        var dDate = new Date(xYear, xMonth, xDay);
        if(new Date(dDate).getTime()>SevenDaysAgo.getTime()){......
```

Does anyone understand this behaviour in SharePoint?